# combining multiple rows and join tables in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

first of all I want to thank everybody who takes the time to help others! This website is great and I already found some solutions for my problems. 
But now I'm stuck and I would like to ask for some help please.
I'm working on a new project where I want to show a chart based on sql table values. It is about weight loss and my users input their data using a form. This datas are stored in 2 tables:

famd0_facileforms_records:

```
id    user_id    username
--------------------------
14    653        username1
15    648        username2
```

famd0_facileforms_subrecords:

```
id    record   element    title        name      type            value
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
199   14       225        Datum        datum     Calendar        2012-08-22 11:32:07
200   14       226        Gewicht      gewicht   Text            92
201   14       242        BMI          bmi       Text            33.79
209   15       225        Datum        datum     Calendar        2012-08-01 11:53:05
210   15       226        Gewicht      gewicht   Text            83
212   15       242        BMI          bmi       Text            26.20
```

I was able to show all the records in a chart by using the following sql query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(d1.value, DATE) AS Datum, CONVERT(d2.value, DECIMAL(5,1)) AS Gewicht  
FROM famd0_facileforms_subrecords AS d1  
INNER JOIN famd0_facileforms_subrecords AS d2 ON d1.record = d2.record  
WHERE d1.element = 225 AND d2.element = 226  
ORDER BY d1.value ASC
```

But I want to have only the records of the logged user in the chart. I can use a variable for the logged in user, for example:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `famd0_facileforms_records` WHERE `user_id` = %%J_USER_ID%%
```

And this is my problem: I have no idea how to join both tables and show only the entries of the logged in user in my chart.

Any help would be great.

Thank's a lot!
webnicole

Comment: select col1,col2,..
from subrecords d1,subrecords d2,records r1
where d1.record=d2.record
and d1.record=r1.id

Comment: Also why do you want to do a self join on subrecords table? Can you use `type` column to differentiate the values in the column `value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to do the following. You will add a `JOIN` to the table `famd0_facileforms_records` and place in the `WHERE` clause a filter on the user_id.:

```
SELECT x.id, 
    CONVERT(d1.value, DATE) AS Datum, 
    CONVERT(d2.value, DECIMAL(5,1)) AS Gewicht
FROM famd0_facileforms_subrecords AS d1
INNER JOIN famd0_facileforms_subrecords AS d2 
    ON d1.record = d2.record
LEFT JOIN famd0_facileforms_records x
    ON d1.record = x.id
WHERE d1.element = 225 
    AND d2.element = 226
    AND x.user_id = %%J_USER_ID%%
ORDER BY d1.value ASC
```

If you are getting an error but you still want to filter by id, you can add the `WHERE` clause and just not include the id in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(d1.value, DATE) AS Datum, 
    CONVERT(d2.value, DECIMAL(5,1)) AS Gewicht
FROM famd0_facileforms_subrecords AS d1
INNER JOIN famd0_facileforms_subrecords AS d2 
    ON d1.record = d2.record
LEFT JOIN famd0_facileforms_records x
    ON d1.record = x.id
WHERE d1.element = 225 
    AND d2.element = 226
    AND x.user_id = %%J_USER_ID%%
ORDER BY d1.value ASC
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. But it doesn't work, I'm getting:  

Error: No rows

Comment: I made a slight change to the query `AND x.user_id = %%J_USER_ID%%` from my original version. Can you try that version?

Comment: Now I get the raw data right but the chart is not displaying, The error message is now:

Error: Vertical stacked bar requires a non-numeric first column and a numeric second column
Plot 1 column 1 [id] is int which is numeric, and column 2 [Datum] is date which is non-numeric
Warning: Y start [50] > first Y value in data [2009-06-01]

Comment: what system is throwing that error message? you only specified sql but not what system.

Comment: Sorry, I work with Joomla and use several components to build the charts. The sql query I have to enter in a component called Plotalot which works with google charts api and there I get the error.

Comment: what version of SQL? mysql, etc

Comment: In Joomla, in the Plotalot component. I was thinking and I hope this question is not too stupid. Your solution works fine as I can see in the raw data table. But as there is a third column now in first place my chart doesn't display and I am getting the mentioned error. Before I had only two columns but of course all the entries were showing. Now the entries are being filtered by logged in user but because of the extra column the chart is not working. So I'm wondering if there is another solution to filter the table by user_id without having the extra column?

Comment: @webnicole happy to help, be sure to mark an answer as accepted for future visitors via the check mark on the left.